# What Ethereum wallet I need

Tags: wallets

I have lots of experience with `bitcoind` and it's RPC calls.

I want similar Ethereum wallet that supports:

- RPC calls from PHP, Pyhton and similar languages.
- erc20 tokens.
- Must work on Linux VPS (I will have 2 TB SSD there)

I want to be able to:

- Send / Receive ETH and erc20 tokens.
- Check transactions.

I think it must be full node, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your own [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) or [Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum) node. Both support JSON-RPC and work on a Linux VPS (with a decently fast SSD), and use a CLI to send transactions. Parity runs a JSON-RPC server by default, and for Geth you can run it with the `--rpc` option. Keep in mind that if you enable JSON-RPC and use Geth or Parity to manage your private keys, the JSON-RPC interface can be used to send transactions, so you definitely don't want to expose it to the public, in that case.

If you're looking for an easy graphical interface, you can use [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com) and [connect it to your own Geth or Parity node](https://support.mycrypto.com/developers/run-your-own-node-with-mycrypto). Here you can also send your ERC-20 tokens.

Comment: do i need full 1 TB  node ?

Comment: If you want to do stuff like looking up transactions by hash, then you need to use a full node. A light node works for the basic JSON-RPC commands, and works if you just want to run a node for MyCrypto.

Comment: Just to be clear, a full node (Geth) is currently 185 GB (not 1 TB): https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault